# The expression being assigned to '....' must be constant

Tags: c#, file, constants

What's wrong with this code?
I get this error: "The expression being assigned to '....' must be constant"

```
public const string ConnectionString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\connection.ini");
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) on `const`?

Comment: A 'const' value has to be known at compile time. In your example you are asking the compiler to go away and execute a random bit of code - which it will not do.

Comment: Your `File.ReadAllText` part is evaluated in runtime, `const` is used to specify a compile-time expressions. You can use `readonly` instead.

Comment: Use `readonly` instead of `const` and make static `public static readonly string ConnectionString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\connection.ini");`, note that now it's simply a field that can be changed only in constructors.

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate.  This question concerns fields with the error, whilst the linked question refers to local variables.  Same error message but different causes & reasons.

Comment: Whenever I need to assign value to C# Const from the expression, I use following syntax which has same effect. Const variables are by default static

private readonly static string Const_NAME= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Key");

Answer (score 55):

A constant value must be known at compile time, use readonly instead, it will have a similar effect

Comment: More similar would be `static readonly`

Comment: @Silvermind You're correct, but `static readonly` does mean there's no sane way to recover from the error if the file doesn't exist when the static constructor is executed, so I don't think that would be an improvement over a `readonly` instance field here.

Comment: @hvd, I agree, but I wouldn't want to load a file like that with every instance I make. The same problem would occur if it could be a constant btw.

Comment: @Silvermind Sure, but there are other ways to let that work without the drawbacks, for example a `static readonly Lazy<string>` field (optionally accessible from a `static string` property), using `LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly` to make sure that if an exception gets thrown, that exception isn't cached.

Comment: @Silvermind BTW, in some cases, it can make sense to re-read such a file every time, which is if you want to support modifying that file while the program is running.

Comment: @hdv, Lazy is a nice solution, but both of your comments disregard the 'const' situation.

Comment: @Silvermind You mean the situation that cannot throw any exception because it doesn't even compile? :)

Comment: @hdv Indeed :) Nice hypothetical sparring with you. I'l leave it at this ;)

Comment: Could I have an extra vote for the comment real estate of mine you guys took up please? :-)

Comment: @StevenWood use readonly instead, it will have a similar effect agree with you . But it is not work for switch case statement

Comment: Whenever I need to assign value to C# Const from the expression, I use following syntax which has same effect. Const variables are by default static

private readonly static string Const_NAME= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Key");